# Do-While loop is showing a lot of error while entering user input (Java -OSGi Equinox in Eclipse EE

Tags: java, osgi, osgi-bundle, equinox

I am new to OSGi Equinox. I am trying to do a Producer-Consumer sample. I have one consumer and 2 producers. When I run the project everything is working fine. Services started and working successfully.

In the consumer I have a Do-While loop where if user enter "no" the loop will continue. If they type "yes" or any other, the loop needs to stop and execute the function I have mentioned.

"no" command is working successfully. But if I type yes or anything it is showing a lot of errors.
This is the beginning of the error. (I can provide full error if needed)

[image: Error]

This is the Do-While loop I have. I tried running the `SubMethod.PrintBill()` function, but still got the same error.

```
private void MainMethod() {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    String user_option="no";
    
    do {
        int serviceType = SubMethod.find();
        
        if(serviceType == 1) {
            ServiceReference service_1 = context.getServiceReference(Vehicle_Interface.class.getName());
            Vehicle_Interface Vehicle_Int =(Vehicle_Interface) context.getService(service_1);
            SubMethod.vehicleService(Vehicle_Int);
            context.ungetService(service_1);
        }
        else if(serviceType == 2) {
            
            ServiceReference service_2 = context.getServiceReference(Food_Interface.class.getName());
            Food_Interface Food_Int =(Food_Interface)context.getService(service_2);
            SubMethod.foodService(Food_Int);
            context.ungetService(service_2);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("");
        }
        System.out.println("Do you want to exit? \n 'yes' for YES \n 'no' for NO");
        user_option = sc.next();
        
    }while(user_option.equals("no"));   
    SubMethod.PrintBill();
    
}
```

Do I need to add any dependencies related to (OSGi) or anything to resolve the issue?
Can someone explain why this error is coming and how to resolve it?

I think the whole code of the project is not necessary. But if needed please ask. I can provide.

Thank-you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is completely unrelated to any Java code (while loop or anything).

Your module (OSGi bundle) `com.sun.xml.bind` with ID `22` can't be *resolved*. The reason is that another module (OSGi bundle) can't be resolved and this module is a bundle with `javax.activation` symbolic name.

The exact reason why `javax.activation` is not resolved is that it requires JDK 9, while you're probably using JDK 8 (or earlier).

The version of `javax.activation` you're using is `1.2.2.v20201119-1642`, which means it is NOT an official bundle available in:

- https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/activation/javax.activation-api/1.2.0/javax.activation-api-1.2.0.jar
- https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/jakarta/activation/jakarta.activation-api/1.2.2/jakarta.activation-api-1.2.2.jar

You're probably using some repackage version of Activation API from Eclipse repositories.
Please either use JDK11+ or replace the Activation bundle with the official one.

Comment: Oh I'll change it and check it. But Every other coding I have typed is working well. Only this while loop exit is showing error. Why is that? Can you explain a bit more

Comment: I can't tell anything just looking at this while loop ;) I see only few OSGi service registry interactions. Also, the stack trace doesn't include anything besides OSGi resolution during start-level increase.